# Facebook Messenger chat widget not loading

Tags: javascript, facebook

[image: Whitelisted domain]
I have whitelisted the domains on our FB page and generated the chat widget. The code did nothing visible on the page (all content blockers disabled).

On our CMS we lack the ability to add code to head/ start or end of body.

I then used the guides from:
https://medium.com/@jamesfuthey/how-to-add-facebook-live-chat-to-your-website-dd48fc8bb066  &&
https://www.labnol.org/internet/embed-facebook-customer-chat-widget/30663/

I.e. creating a developer app and using APP_ID.
This also did not work see: https://www.trentstudents.org/test-fb1

I have also tried manually adding the script to the page in the correct place i.e.

```
var facebookWidget = `
<div class="fb-customerchat" page_id="127611563950728"></div>
<script>

  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId            : '383830712455959',
      autoLogAppEvents : true,
      xfbml            : true,
      version          : 'v2.11'
    });
  };

  (function(d, s, id){
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk/xfbml.customerchat.js";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

</script>
`;
$('body').prepend(facebookWidget);
```

Finally I attempted copying and editing the code from https://www.lsu.co.uk/
Sample page here:
https://www.trentstudents.org/test-fb2

Blocked by iframe origin policy (I attempted to mod the code ids and domains to ours - clearly I missed something)

```
    <div id="fb-root" class=" fb_reset"><div style="position: absolute; top: -10000px; width: 0px; height: 0px;">
<div>
<iframe name="fb_xdm_frame_https" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" allowfullscreen="true" scrolling="no" allow="encrypted-media" id="fb_xdm_frame_https" aria-hidden="true" title="Facebook Cross Domain Communication Frame" tabindex="-1" src="https://staticxx.facebook.com/connect/xd_arbiter/r/vy-MhgbfL4v.js?version=44#channel=f1f65df83379dd4&amp;origin=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.lsu.co.uk" style="border: none;"></iframe></div><div></div></div><div class="fb-customerchat fb_invisible_flow fb_iframe_widget" attribution="setup_tool" page_id="127611563950728" logged_in_greeting="Hi! ðŸ‘‹  How can we help you?" logged_out_greeting="Hi! ðŸ‘‹  How can we help you?" fb-xfbml-state="rendered" fb-iframe-plugin-query="app_id=383830712455959&amp;attribution=setup_tool&amp;container_width=0&amp;locale=en_US&amp;logged_in_greeting=Hi!%20%F0%9F%91%8B%20%20How%20can%20we%20help%20you%3F&amp;logged_out_greeting=Hi!%20%F0%9F%91%8B%20%20How%20can%20we%20help%20you%3F&amp;page_id=10144058117&amp;sdk=joey"><span style="vertical-align: bottom; width: 1000px; height: 0px;"><iframe name="f105c6e6d6280d4" width="1000px" height="1000px" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" allowfullscreen="true" scrolling="no" allow="encrypted-media" title="" src="https://www.facebook.com/v3.2/plugins/customerchat.php?app_id=383830712455959&amp;attribution=setup_tool&amp;channel=https%3A%2F%2Fstaticxx.facebook.com%2Fconnect%2Fxd_arbiter%2Fr%2Fvy-MhgbfL4v.js%3Fversion%3D44%23cb%3Dfac9b0f08f1698%26domain%3Dwww.lsu.co.uk%26origin%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fwww.lsu.co.uk%252Ff1f65df83379dd4%26relation%3Dparent.parent&amp;container_width=0&amp;locale=en_US&amp;logged_in_greeting=Hi!%20%F0%9F%91%8B%20%20How%20can%20we%20help%20you%3F&amp;logged_out_greeting=Hi!%20%F0%9F%91%8B%20%20How%20can%20we%20help%20you%3F&amp;page_id=10144058117&amp;sdk=joey" style="border: none; visibility: visible; width: 288pt; height: 214px; border-radius: 9pt; bottom: 63pt; padding: 0px; position: fixed; right: 9pt; top: auto; z-index: 2147483647; max-height: 100%;" class=" fb_customer_chat_bounce_in_v2" data-testid="dialog_iframe"></iframe></span></div><div class="fb_dialog  fb_dialog_advanced fb_customer_chat_bubble_animated_no_badge fb_customer_chat_bubble_pop_in" style="background: none; border-radius: 50%; bottom: 18pt; display: inline; height: 45pt; padding: 0px; position: fixed; right: 18pt; top: auto; width: 45pt; z-index: 2147483646;"><div class="fb_dialog_content" style="background: none;"><iframe name="blank_f105c6e6d6280d4" width="60px" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" allowfullscreen="true" scrolling="no" allow="encrypted-media" tabindex="-1" data-testid="bubble_iframe" src="https://staticxx.facebook.com/connect/xd_arbiter/r/vy-MhgbfL4v.js?version=44#forIframe=f105c6e6d6280d4" style="border: none;"></iframe></div></div></div> <script> window.fbAsyncInit=function() {
    FB.init( {
        appId: '383830712455959', autoLogAppEvents: true, xfbml: true, version: 'v3.2'
    }
    );
}

;
(function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js=d.createElement(s);
    js.id=id;
    js.src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk/xfbml.customerchat.js";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}

(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
```

Finally in trying to go back to the facebook page and generated new code it no longer works.
Video here:
https://tinytake.s3.amazonaws.com/pulse/d-manicx100/attachments/9953495/TinyTake20-02-2019-10-31-20.mp4

Original generated code below (includes custom theme color):

```
    <!-- Load Facebook SDK for JavaScript -->
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      xfbml            : true,
      version          : 'v3.2'
    });
  };

  (function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = 'https://connect.facebook.net/en_GB/sdk/xfbml.customerchat.js';
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

<!-- Your customer chat code -->
<div class="fb-customerchat"
  attribution=setup_tool
  page_id="127611563950728"
  theme_color="#6E7377">
</div>
```

Seen here:
https://www.trentstudents.org/test-fb3

Answer (score 0):

The answer was that a css file from an external library was blocking it with

```
.fb_reset#fb-root {display:none;}
```

Strangely the official SDK version still didn't work only the one with APP_ID. I also set the version to 4.4 as referenced in the JS file (as of 20th February 2019)

Final working code:

```
<script>
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
  FB.init({
    appId : '383830712455959',
    autoLogAppEvents : true,
    xfbml : true,
    version : 'v4.4'
  });
};

(function(d, s, id){
var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk/xfbml.customerchat.js";
fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
<div attribution="setup_tool" class="fb-customerchat" minimised="false" page_id="127611563950728" theme_color="#6E7377">&nbsp;</div>
```